# escape to bb code in php

Tags: php, bbcode

how do i use the bb code url [url[/url] and save that in an variable in php? In other words I want to store some bb code into a php variable, how to escape into it?

something like this

```
$myvariable = 'Please like us on Facebook [url=http://facebook/page]text[/url]'
```

Comment: @Brady i am gettinh unexpected T_STRING expecting ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into this: http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/

Its the BBCode parser I use on my website :)

If not you could use regular expressions with preg_replace() but I would seriously suggest the above solution so you don't have to worry about security.

Comment: any reason why i am getting this error?  unexpected T_STRING expecting ')

Comment: Oh, Brady's has an extra ) on the end of the $replace line as the error says :)  It should be `replace = "<a href='\\1' target='_blank'>\\2</a>";`

Comment: it seems it needs to escape the http:// bit as it marks the rest of the variable as an comment, any idea how to escape it?

Comment: Assuming it is encapsulated in the "'s which make it a string it should not be thinking that it is a comment.  Double check that all of your parentheses and quotes are matching, if not post your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, altering it for your liking, but the syntax is here.

```
$str = "Please like us on Facebook [url=http://facebook/page]text[/url]"

$pattern = "/\[url=(.*)\](.+)\[\/url\]/Usi";
$replace = "<a href='\\1' target='_blank'>\\2</a>");
$str = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$str);
```